# How to connect to EventHubs with Apache-Kafka extension using Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, azure-functions

Can I use SharedAccessKey to connect to the broker (EventHubs)?

I'm unable to connect to my Azure EventHubs.

We use SharedAccessKey instead of SSL to get connected and I have this configuration to do it.

```
"EventBusConfig": {

    "BootstrapServers": "anyname.servicebus.windows.net:9093",

    "SecurityProtocol": "SaslSsl",

    "SaslMechanism": "Plain",

    "SaslUsername": "$ConnectionString",

    "SaslPassword": 
    "Endpoint=sb://anyname.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=anyname.;SharedAccessKey=CtDbJ/Kfjs749
    8s--anypassword--SkSk749/z2Z5Fr9///33/qQ+R6Cyg=",

    "SocketTimeoutMs": "60000",

    "SessionTimeoutMs": "30000",

    "GroupId": "NameOfTheGroup",

    "AutoOffsetReset": "Earliest",

    "BrokerVersionFallback": "1.0.0",

    "Debug": "cgrp"
}
```

But it seems I need the certification path (the pem file)

I want to produce a simple message like this

[image]

I'm using https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension but I don't know if this beta library can handle SharedAccessKey.

I got this error when trying to connect:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I was able to produce and consume messages using the extension "https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension".

To consume a message was easy because of the property "EventHubConnectionString" very intuitive.

To produce a message you need to configure a CA certificate, I thought that I need this from Azure but I was wrong and I just followed these instructions to make it work.

> Download and set the CA certification location. As described in Confluent documentation, the .NET library does not have the capability to access root CA certificates.
>   Missing this step will cause your function to raise the error "sasl_ssl://xyz-xyzxzy.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092/bootstrap: Failed to verify broker certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate (after 135ms in state CONNECT)"
>
> To overcome this, we need to:
>
> - Download CA certificate (i.e. from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).
> - Rename the certificate file to anything other than cacert.pem to avoid any conflict with existing EventHubs Kafka certificate that is part of the extension.
> - Include the file in the project, setting "copy to output directory"
> - Set the SslCaLocation trigger attribute property. In the example, we set to confluent_cloud_cacert.pem

This is my producer Azure function with Kafka binding

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka;

namespace EY.Disruptor.AzureFunctionsWithKafka
{
public static class Function
{
    [FunctionName("Producer")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Kafka("BootstrapServer",
            "topic.event",
            Username = "ConfluentCloudUsername",
            Password = "ConfluentCloudPassword",
            SslCaLocation = "confluent_cloud_cacert.pem",
            AuthenticationMode = BrokerAuthenticationMode.Plain,
            Protocol = BrokerProtocol.SaslSsl
        )] IAsyncCollector<KafkaEventData<string>> events,
            ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name ??= data?.name;

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        var kafkaEvent = new KafkaEventData<string>()
        {
            Value = name
        };

        await events.AddAsync(kafkaEvent);

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
}
```

This is my consume Azure function with Kafka binding

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace EY.Disruptor.AzureFunctionsWithKafka
{
public static class Consumer
{
    [FunctionName("FunctionKafkaConsumer")]
    public static void Run(
        [KafkaTrigger("BootstrapServer",
        "topic.event",
        Username = "ConfluentCloudUsername",
        Password = "ConfluentCloudPassword",
        EventHubConnectionString = "ConfluentCloudPassword",
        AuthenticationMode = BrokerAuthenticationMode.Plain,
        Protocol = BrokerProtocol.SaslSsl,
        ConsumerGroup = "Group1")] KafkaEventData<string>[] kafkaEvents,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        foreach (var kafkaEvent in kafkaEvents)
        {
            logger.LogInformation(kafkaEvent.Value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
     "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
     "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
     "BootstrapServer": "zyxabc.servicebus.windows.net:9093",
     "ConfluentCloudUsername": "$ConnectionString",
     "ConfluentCloudPassword": "Endpoint=sb://zyxabc.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=TestSvc;SharedAccessKey=YAr/="
   }
}
```

And of course the initialization in the Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
{
   builder.AddKafka();
}
```

I hope this recommendation helps other people :)